# When and where woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification hook is executed in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, composite

I have WooCommerce 8.0.3 installed on my e-shop. In short, let's say I have an order with ID 123 in status `processing`. In a specific situation, I'm running this code:

```
// Make sure e-mails are initialized.
WC()->mailer();

// Set order status to completed.
$order = wc_get_order( 123 );
$order->update_status( "completed", "", true );
```

I need a `customer_completed_order` e-mail to be sent. Sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesn't. I have the e-mail enabled in WooCommerce admin.

I found an e-mail is triggered on `woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification` hook, so I tried to modify the code:

```
WC()->mailer();
$order = wc_get_order( 123 );
$order->update_status( "completed", "", true );

var_dump( did_action( "woocommerce_order_status_completed" ) );
var_dump( did_action( "woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification" ) );
```

Result:

```
int(1)
int(0)
```

Which means `woocommerce_order_status_completed` hook was executed, but `woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification` wasn't.

My questions are:

1. Where in WooCommerce code are hooks like `woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification` executed?
2. What can be the reason that hook `woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification` isn't executed when `woocommerce_order_status_completed` is?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook `woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification` is a **multi composite hook** that allows to trigger the email sent to the customer when order status is changed to "completed".

It's triggered in [`WC_Emails` `send_transactional_email()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.1/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L170) on line 170:

```php
do_action_ref_array( current_filter() . '_notification', $args );
```

where `current_filter()` refer to [`woocommerce_email_actions` filter hook **arguments**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.1/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L80-L105):

```php
array(
    'woocommerce_low_stock',
    'woocommerce_no_stock',
    'woocommerce_product_on_backorder',
    'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing',
    'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed',
    'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_cancelled',
    'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_failed',
    'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold',
    'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing',
    'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed',
    'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold',
    'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_processing',
    'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_completed',
    'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_on-hold',
    'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_processing',
    'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_cancelled',
    'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_failed',
    'woocommerce_order_status_completed', // <=== <=== <=== HERE
    'woocommerce_order_fully_refunded',
    'woocommerce_order_partially_refunded',
    'woocommerce_new_customer_note',
    'woocommerce_created_customer',
)
```

The hook is hooked in [`WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order` in the constructor function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.1/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-completed-order.php#L42) line 42, for the `WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order` method `trigger()`:

```php
// Triggers for this email.
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
```

So **you can only use this hook with `remove_action()`** [as showed in this code snippet](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/docs/code-snippets/unhook--remove-woocommerce-emails.md?plain=1#L38), to remove the email notification sent to the customer when order status is "completed".

---

Note that `WC()->mailer()` is just an instance object of the `WC_Emails` Class, that load the mailer class, similar to `new WC_Emails()`.